# Mongoose allow extra fields on document update?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I initially created my model, like:

```
var schema = new Schema(){ 
  property1: { type: String },
  property2: { type: String }
}
```

On creation, any additional property are excluded:

```
var myDocument = new Schema({ property1: "hello", property2:"test", property3:{prop:"hey"} } });

// myDocument = { property1: "hello", property2:"test" }
```

However, when I do a findOneAndUpdate, the extra field is saved to the DB!

```
Schema.findOneAndUpdate( property1:"hello", { property3:{prop:"hey"} } })

// In the DB: { property1: "hello", property2:"test", property3:{} } }
```

How can I make sure to NOT save the extra fields on update?

I was thinking about using pre-processing the object and remove the extra fields... But I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Mongoose 3.x or 4.x. Are you sure you're not using the _MongoDB_  driver's [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) somehow?

Comment: I edited the question: property3 is an object: property3:{prop:"hey"}. I tested again and here is the result: { property1: "hello", property2:"test", property3:{} } }. As you can see, the property3 was added to the document, but it should not as the schema only accept property1 and property2 !

Comment: What version of Mongoose are you using? And can you show the actual code, or an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: In my package.json, I found my project uses 3.8.25